# Put favicon in middle of Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, favicon

I tried to find on different websites the solution to my problem but couldn't find one.

I am using highcharts to display a beautiful chart (cf picture below).

[Beautiful chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB3SN.png)

I would like to add to this chart an icon (Font awesome web application icon) at the middle of the circle.

I found an example (cf picture below) where some text is added at the center of it.

[Chart with text in it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH1w4.png)

The code to display this chart is as follow:

```
/* Renders a pie chart using the provided chartops */
var renderPieChart = function (chartopts) {
    return Highcharts.chart(chartopts['elemId'], {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    var chart = this,                                                                     
                        rend = chart.renderer,                                                            
                        pie = chart.series[0],                                                            
                        left = chart.plotLeft + pie.center[0],                                            
                        top = chart.plotTop + pie.center[1];                                              
                    this.innerText = rend.text(chartopts['data'][0].y, left, top).                        
                    attr({                                                                                
                        'text-anchor': 'middle',                                                          
                        'font-size': '24px',                                                              
                        'font-weight': 'bold',                                                            
                        'fill': chartopts['colors'][0],                                                   
                        'font-family': 'Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif'                                       
                    }).add();                                                                             
                },                                                                                        
                render: function () {                                                                     
                    this.innerText.attr({                                                                 
                        text: chartopts['data'][0].y                                                      
                    })                                                                                    
                }                                                                                         
            }                                                                                             
        },                                                                                                
        title: {                                                                                          
            text: chartopts['title']                                                                      
        },                                                                                                
        plotOptions: {                                                                                    
            pie: {                                                                                        
                innerSize: '80%',                                                                         
                dataLabels: {                                                                             
                    enabled: false                                                                        
                }                                                                                         
            }                                                                                             
        },                                                                                                
        credits: {                                                                                        
            enabled: false                                                                                
        },                                                                                                
        tooltip: {                                                                                        
            formatter: function () {                                                                      
                if (this.key == undefined) {                                                              
                    return false                                                                          
                }                                                                                         
                return '<span style="color:' + this.color + '">\u25CF</span>' + this.point.name + ': <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>'   
            }
        },  
        series: [{                                                                                        
            data: chartopts['data'],                                                                      
            colors: chartopts['colors'],                                                                  
        }]
    })
}
```

What do I have to change in this code so I'm able to add an icon?

Thanks,

Cycl0pe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to import the **CSS** and use `SVGRenderer.text` (`useHTML` enabled):

```
  load: function() {
    this.renderer.text("<i style='font-size:24px' class='fa'>&#xf2b9;</i>", 290, 220, true).add();
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mpL2chhe/